# How to format string date in yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss format to normal date in flutter (dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, date

I've only found the reverse answer to this (normal date to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss) but in my case, I have a string in a yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss format that I want to cast to date in order to display something like dd/MM/yyyy.

Does anybody have any idea? Thanks

Comment: Can you include date formatter

Comment: Yes I can use intl date formatter, but I havent found an example of String to date, only the reverse (date to string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think below code is what you want. just try this.

```
var parsedDate = DateTime.parse('1974-03-20 00:00:00.000');
String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(parsedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to look at the intl package